# Production Build a Angular (4) project, with a separate individual file

Tags: angular, angular-cli

So this is what is happening. I have my project, and it has a configuration file. This configuration includes information about the app that only the client knows when they go into production mode. But we don't want to give the full source code of the rest of the application, so we do have to build. But when I execute `ng build --prod` this bundles and minifies *all* of my files. I still want this, but instead of doing this for all the files in the project, it should keep the configuration file separate.

```
inline.bundle.js
polyfills.bundle.js
styles.bundle.js
vendor.bundle.js
main.bundle.js
```

This should become the following:

```
inline.bundle.js
polyfills.bundle.js
styles.bundle.js
vendor.bundle.js
main.bundle.js
configuration.js
```

All the code is turned into JavaScript. Everything is bundled and minified, except for the configuration file.

I can not find any documentation about this, I was hoping there would be a flag, or a setting in `.angular-cli.json`.

Comment: You can add the configuration file manually if it's just a `.js` file. angular-cli doesn't give access to the webpack configuration easily.

Comment: You need to `ng eject` and proceed from there, you can't do this with the regular config.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need a file which has configuration and you do not want to bundle it. To do so you simply can put the file in `assets` folder, and reference the variables from there.

**.angular-cli.json**

```
"assets": [
  "assets"
]
```

you may also have the file somewhere else in the project but you need to configure the same in `.angular-cli.json` file.

Read more about [asset configuration here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-asset-configuration).

Hope this helps!!

Comment: No this doesn't work, since it is a Typescript file, so it needs to be compiled to JavaScript as well.

Comment: @broodjetom, Oh I thought its just a simple configuration which may reside as JavaScript, any reason you can not make it  a JS file?

Comment: Yes because it is a barrel and configuration at the same time.

Comment: Hmm, did you try segregating two?